# Test whether the variance in one group is higher than In another

Tags: variance, biostatistics, vector-autoregression

I have 63 groups of microbes that elicit a specific reaction of the immune system (cell frequency). In each group, there are 3-10 replicates and I want to check in which groups the variance is significantly higher than in other groups.

Can you please suggest a method to check it out? (Note that I can't assume that the data is distributed under a normal distribution).

Comment: You should really give some more context! The response variable is a "specific reaction of the immune system", is it a count? That could indicate poisson regression, and since for a poisson distribution the variance is equal to the mean, comparing variances is the same as comparing means! But if the counts are large, there will probably be overdispersion, which could be modelled as quasi-poisson (where variance is still proportional to mean) or with negative binomial models. Maybe you could post here a link to the data? or at least some plots.

Answer (score 0):

The classical test to compare two variances is the F test (which is why it is used inside an ANOVA).

You can do a pairwise F test (dividing the variance of a group by the variance of another group). However this is not recommended for your entire dataset, since you would have to do $63^2$ comparisons, and that will require a strong Bonferroni correction.

Comment: The F test for variance is pretty sensitive to the assumption of normality. The OP indicates that they cannot assume normality.